# Airflow: How do I access the variables run_id, task_id, dag_id and attempt nr. in Airflow?

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I would like to attach the log-file of an Airflow task to an e-mail that gets sent if the task failed. The log file names have the format `dag_id={dag_id}/run_id={run_id}/task_id={task_id}/attempt={try_number}.log`.
In order to load the log file, I need to access the current dag_id, run_id, task_id and try_number. I know, that I can use the context dictionary (https://composed.blog/airflow/execute-context) to fetch the current run_id:

```
def load_log_path(**context):
    run_id = context['run_id']
```

How do I access the other variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the task_instance

```
    ti : TaskInstance=context['ti']
    print(ti.try_number, ti.dag_id, ti.run_id, ti.task_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need to add 'ti :' before TaskInstance?

Comment: you can write, ti =context['ti] (i add the type for understanding)

Comment: @Cipher187, please accept my answer. 10x